# Loop loops, yet still having difficulties understanding

Tags: c, loops, cs50

I am currently going though the online course CS50.  The objective is to create a set of stairs found within the first level of Mario, like the one made from hashtags below. I've gotten to the point of being able to print the height of how high the user entered, yet my loop will not indent any of the hashtags to make the stairs. Any ideas?

**What it should look like**

```
   ##
  ###
 ####
#####
```

**What it mine looks like**

```
#
#
#
#
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int line = 0;
    int blockHeight = blockHeight - 1;
    int space = blockHeight - 1;
    int hashes = 2;

    do
    {
        printf("please give me a number between the range of 1 and 23:\n");
        scanf("%i", &blockHeight);
    }

    while (blockHeight >= 1 != blockHeight <= 23);
    {
        printf("thanks for the correct answer!\n");
    }

    printf("\n\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < blockHeight; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < space; j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
            space--;
            break;
        }

    for (int k = 0; k < hashes; k++)
        {
            printf("#");
            hashes++;
            break;
        }

        for (int z = 0; z < blockHeight; z++)
        {
            printf("\n");
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What is this `blockHeight >= 1 != blockHeight <= 23` supposed to do?

Comment: I don't think you want to decrement `space` inside the `j` loop.

Comment: in the loop where you are printing `#` you have written `break;` so every time it will print only 1 `#` and exit the loop. Remove `break;` from that loop and keep `hashes++` outside the loop.

Comment: Initialize blockHeight to 0. (int blockHeight = 0; )  I'm surprised it compiles as it is written here, though I suspect you may have miscopied it.

Comment: Your `do...while` loop is the most evil form of obfuscation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**

```
int blockHeight = blockHeight - 1;
int space = blockHeight - 1;
```

This is the wrong way to intialize the variable.
change it to

```
int blockHeight, space;
```

After getting the value of `blockHeight` you can assign `space = blockHeight - 1;` (after do-while loop)

**2.**

```
do
{
    printf("please give me a number between the range of 1 and 23:\n");
    scanf("%i", &blockHeight);
}
while (blockHeight < 1 || blockHeight > 23); // write `||` instead of `!=`
printf("thanks for the correct answer!\n");
```

it will run `do` untill the condition is satisfied. After the condition is satisfied it will print the message written after `while`.
**3.**

```
for (int j = 0; j < space; j++)
{
    printf(" ");
    space--;
    break;
}
```

Change this to

```
for (int j = 0; j < space; j++)
{
    printf(" ");
}
space--;
```

because you have written `break;` in your loop so for loop will work only once and it will exit the loop.

**4.**

```
for (int k = 0; k < hashes; k++)
{
    printf("#");
    hashes++;
    break;
}
```

Change this to

```
for (int k = 0; k < hashes; k++)
{
    printf("#");
}
hashes++;
```

As because of `break;` it will print `#` once and exit the loop.

**5.**

```
for (int z = 0; z < blockHeight; z++)
{
    printf("\n");
    break;
}
```

No need to write this for loop. Just one line is enough. Change this to

```
printf("\n");
```

**6.**

```
int main(void)
{
   ////
   // your code
   ////

    return 0; // write this line at the end
}
```

Comment: in (2) you want the `while` condition inverted . Also it'd be good to check for input error, to avoid an infinite loop if they type in letters.

Comment: `while (blockHeight < 1 && blockHeight > 23)` can never evaluate to true. `blockHeight` can't be less than 1 and greater than 23 at the same time.

Comment: @sendaran `while (blockHeight < 1 || blockHeight > 23);` will work. Thanks for pointing mistake.

Comment: `while (blockHeight < 1 || blockHeight > 23); ` is still confusing only because  [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f355wky8.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) states that "The second operand is evaluated only if the first operand evaluates to false (0)".  If I were to enter -1, wouldn't it read as true since -1 is indeed less then 1?

Comment: @Carsol yes it would read as true, so the loop continues and asks for another input

Answer (score 1):

`while (blockHeight >= 1 != blockHeight <= 23);` This is not a valid statement.

1. The operand `!=` is not used in such statements. Use boolean operators(`&&`, `||`) instead.

Also there are un-necessary `{}` for the block after the do-while loop.

---

The reason for a single `#` is because of the unconditional `break`. Which breaks after printing a single space.

```
for (int j = 0; j < space; j++)
{
    printf(" ");
    space--;//You don't want to decrement space here
    break;// condition less breaks shouldn't be used. This stat
}
```

The same applies to the other loops

Comment: I think it is intended to be a do-while loop here.  Really the OP should remove the braces around the "Thanks for the correct answer!"

Comment: @jeffcarey Thanks, That's right. I was confused. Edited the answer though.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is "unconditional" break.

Comment: @PeterCordes You got me ;)

Comment: the `while` is a valid statement, but it doesn't do what OP intended

Comment: @M.M: I noticed that, too.  I just checked, and `!=` has [lower precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `>=` / `<=`, so it's checking that the truth-values of the two comparisons aren't equal.  i.e. it's doing a logical XOR, just like `&&` does a logical AND.  (except you can't short-circuit XOR; you always need to evaluate both operands.  This, and fact that it wouldn't get used, are probably why C doesn't have a `^^` logical-XOR, only a bitwise `^` XOR.)

Comment: More importantly, the OP should use an `if`, not a `while`, in that spot.  Oops, nvm, that's the most misleading indentation and spacing *ever*.  The `while` goes with the preceding `do{}` block, not the `{ printf(); }` block that it's right on top of.  I can't imagine why you'd write it that way unless you were trying to literally trick people into misreading it.